# Python: Scopus Author Citations

Tags: python, web-scraping, citations, scopus

I want to extract the citations an other has received from Scopus. If you use the Scopus webpage you can access a citation overview for each author and select specific citations for specific years. For example <2016, <2019, etc.

Is it possible to extract this information through the API?
I tried the following but this only gives me the Scopus IDs of the authors articles. I would need a sum of all citations received for articles before a given year.

```
resp = requests.get(
   "http://api.elsevier.com/content/search/scopus",
   params={
       "query": "au-id(34167797100) AND PUBYEAR < 2013",
       "start": "0",
       "count": "10",
   },
   headers={"X-ELS-APIKey": key, "Accept": "application/json"},
)
#alle papers zum author holen
data = resp.json()
total_results = data["search-results"]["opensearch:totalResults"]
results = []
for i in range(0, int(total_results), 25):
   resp = requests.get(
       "http://api.elsevier.com/content/search/scopus",
       params={
           "query": "au-id(34167797100) AND PUBYEAR < 2013",
           "start": i,
           "count": "25",
       },
       headers={"X-ELS-APIKey": key, "Accept": "application/json"},
   )
   results.extend(resp.json()["search-results"]["entry"])

liste_scopus_id = []
Path("resp.json").write_text(dumps(results, indent=4))
for result in results:

    liste_scopus_id.append(result["dc:identifier"].split(":")[1])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share some links and more information about what you have tried so far. Thank you. You may find this helpful: https://dev.elsevier.com/

Comment: @dcsuka added some further information

Comment: If you can get the Scopus IDs for every article, why don't you use the scopus citation count API and regular abstract API on each of the Scopus IDs to get the relevant citation info and year for each article, and then sum it up for each author by year? The different API types are at the bottom here: https://dev.elsevier.com/academic_research_scopus.html